# Proper testing of Auth flow with Redux Saga actions

Tags: unit-testing, redux-saga

I'm just using simple old Jest to test my new Saga actions. After a lot of struggling I learned that rather than mocking responses, I should just include my response in the next call to the generator. The following test of the following function passes:

### function

```js
import { put, call, takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects";

export function* loginSaga({ username, password }) {
  const creds = { username, password };
  try {
    let data = yield call(() => axios.get(ApiUrls.login, { params: creds }));
    yield put({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", user: data });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", error });
  }
}
```

### test

```js
    it("should return a user object on a successful login", () => {
      gen = loginSaga(success.creds);
      gen.next(); // call api
      expect(gen.next(loginResponse.success).value).toEqual(
        put({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", user: loginResponse.success.data })
      );
    });
```

But wait a minute! The test doesn't take the credentials into account at all! My test passes no matter what credentials I call `loginSaga()` with because it's not actually making the API call, even a mocked one!

I had set up these objects to feed my calls to `fetchMock` or `axios-mock-adapter`:

```js
success = {
  url: ApiUrls.Login + "?username=testuser1&password=123123",
  creds: { username: "testuser1", password: "123123" }
};
badUser = {
  url: success.url.replace("testuser", "xxx"),
  creds: { username: "xxx", password: "123123" }
};
badPw = {
  url: success.url + "0",
  creds: { username: "testuser1", password: "1231230" }
};
```

But this method of testing doesn't use them!

How am I supposed to actually make this test effective?

Comment: your function and test are the same, please update your test code

Comment: I've added the tests, sorry!